# R notebook table formatting

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R notebook and I want to make a table.

[image: r notebook screen]
or like this:

But when I 'Preview' it, I get this

```
|gender           | male                          | female                        |
| diabetes--------| Y-------------| N-------------| Y-------------| N-------------| 
| age group       | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|                 |               |               |               |               |
| None            | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 |
| R               | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 |
| I1              | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 |
| R-I1            | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 |
| I1-R            | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 |
| I1-I2           | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 |
| R-I1-I2         | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 |
| I1-R-I2         | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 |
| I1-I2-R         | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 | p0| p1| p2|p3 |
```

[image: or like this.]

could you help me to make a table that I would like to generate?

Comment: I don't think the table formats in RMarkdown allow you to have tables where you have a single header cell above multiple columns - if you're outputting to PDF or HTML you can do more complex tables using Latex or HTML code, and there are some packages that will help you do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `kable` package

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(
    matrix(c(
     "None","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3",
     "R","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3",
     "I1","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3",
     "R-I1","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3",
     "I1-R","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3",
     "I1-I2","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3",
     "R-I1-I2","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3",
     "I1-R-I2","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3",
     "I1-I2-R","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3","p0","p1","p2","p3"), 
    nrow = 9, byrow = TRUE), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

kable(df, col.names = rep("", ncol(df))) %>% 
  kable_styling() %>%
  add_header_above(c("age group" = 1,"0" = 1,"1" = 1,"2" = 1,"3" = 1,"0" = 1,"1" = 1,"2" = 1,"3" = 1,
                 "0" = 1,"1" = 1,"2" = 1,"3" = 1,"0" = 1,"1" = 1,"2" = 1,"3" = 1)) %>%
  add_header_above(c("diabetes" = 1, "Y" = 4, "N" = 4, "Y" = 4, "N" = 4)) %>%
  add_header_above(c("gender" = 1, "male" = 8, "female" = 8))
```